# WPF update binding in a background thread

Tags: wpf, data-binding, multithreading

I have a control that has its data bound to a standard `ObservableCollection`, and I have a background task that calls a service to get more data.

I want to, then, update my backing data behind my control, while displaying a "please wait" dialog, but when I add the new items to the collection, the UI thread locks up while it re-binds and updates my controls.

Can I get around this so that my animations and stuff keep running on my "please wait" dialog?

Or at least give the "appearance" to the user that its not locked up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you already use a BackgroundWorker to retrieve the data, and that simply assigning this data to the ObservableCollection is locking up the UI.

One way to avoid locking up the UI is to assign the data to the ObservableCollection in smaller chunks by queuing multiple dispatcher methods. Between each method call, UI events can be handled.

the following would add one item on at a time, that's a bit extreme, but it illustrates the concept.

```
void UpdateItems()
{
    //retrievedItems is the data you received from the service
    foreach(object item in retrievedItems)
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ParameterizedThreadStart(AddItem), item);    
}

void AddItem(object item)
{
    observableCollection.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: So by adding them to the items collection in a background thread will update the controls on the UI thread? How does that work?

Comment: No, you add them in the dispatcher thread, but with a lower priority and in smaller chucnks so the UI remains responsive

Answer (score 10):

ObservableCollection will raise CollectionChanged events that will force UI to rebind data, measure, arrange and redraw. This might take a lot of time if you have many updates coming.

It is possible to make user think that UI is alive by splitting the job in small packages. Use Dispatcher from UI thread (any control has reference to it) to schedule collection update actions with 10-100 items (determine number by experiment, these just to support the idea).

Your background code might looks like this:

```
void WorkInBackground()
{
    var results = new List<object>();

    //get results...

    // feed UI in packages no more than 100 items
    while (results.Count > 0)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action<List<object>>(FeedUI),
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            results.GetRange(0, Math.Min(results.Count, 100)));
        results.RemoveRange(0, Math.Min(results.Count, 100));
    }
}
void FeedUI(List<object> items)
{
    // items.Count must be small enough to keep UI looks alive
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        MyCollection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a DLL which runs a worker thread and sends events back to the application - worked perfectly on windows forms, switched to WPF and everything stopped working. I've been smashing my head against a brick wall for 4 hours trying to get this to work. But the solution I ended up with, thanks to Microsoft's UI Thread Safe marshalling EnableCollectionSynchronization, gives a really clean implementation to solve this.

This Collection extends ObservableCollection and implements EnableCollectionSynchronization making these objects usable between WPF and also background workers.

***Edit***: [Microsoft's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) say the following, so I'm going to assume that the object context sharing doesn't matter.

> The context parameter is an arbitrary object that you can use to information known when you enable collection synchronization. Context can be ***null***.

***ThreadSafeCollection.cs***

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace NSYourApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This ObservableCollection is thread safe
    /// You can update it from any thread and the changes will be safely
    /// marshalled to the UI Thread WPF bindings
    /// Thanks Microsoft!
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Whatever type of collection you want!</typeparam>
    public class ThreadSafeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        private static object __threadsafelock = new object();

        public ThreadSafeCollection()
        {
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, __threadsafelock);
        }
    }
}
```

Example WindowViewModel
***WindowViewModel.cs***

```
namespace NSYourApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Example View 
    /// BaseModelView implements "PropertyChanged" to update WPF automagically
    /// </summary>
    class TestViewModel : BaseModelView
    {
        public ThreadSafeCollection<string> StringCollection { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// background thread implemented elsewhere...
        /// but it calls this method eventually ;)
        /// Depending on the complexity you might want to implement
        /// [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        /// to Synchronize multiple threads to prevent chase-conditions,deadlocks etc
        /// </summary>
        public void NonUIThreadMethod()
        {
            // No dispatchers or invokes required here!
            StringCollection.Add("Some Text from a background worker");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Somewhere in the UIThread code it'll call this method
        /// </summary>
        public void UIThreadMethod()
        {
            StringCollection.Add("This text come from UI Thread");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor, creates a thread-safe collection
        /// </summary>
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            StringCollection = new ThreadSafeCollection<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in a listbox in a xaml window/control
***MainWindow.xaml***

```
    <ListBox x:Name="wpfStringCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding StringCollection,Mode=OneWay}">

    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Hmm thinking about it; this single static __threadsafelock is going to be shared by all the collections; this might cause problems ;) I'll have to come back to this ... =]

Answer (score 0):

use BackgroundWorker to accomplish this task. update the obsrvablecollection in the DoWork method

Comment: How does that update the UI thread? Maybe im not understanding this, but arent all my controls and the rendering behind them within the UI thread, so updating the collection in a background thread will just cause the UI thread to do the normal update?

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(UpdateData), value);

private void UpdateData(int value)
{
  BindingSourceProperty = value;
}
```

Comment: lets say you have a WPF UI form having ProgressBar control as <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Path=PercentValue}" /> where PercentValue is property defined in your DataContext attached to form. Assuming a scenario where you are getting callback data on some other thread indicating progress of operation and you want to display it on UI. If you set that value directly to your dependency source property 'PercentValue', you will get updated ui only when background thread operation is finished. So in order to get real time progress of percent value, set this value as above