# Updating a TreeView ItemsSource in another thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, treeview, itemssource

I have a function like this:

```
public void UpdateList()
{
BindList = Model.GetList();
TreeView1.ItemsSource = BindList;
}
```

UpdateList() needs to be called (and the tree view list therefore reloaded) every time the user performs some action. It currently works, it's just very slow so I want to do it in another thread.

I am quite new to WPF... on WinForms programs I used to make delegates and check if InvokeRequired, etc. But I have found this does not work in WPF.

So if I want to call UpdateList() such that it runs in another thread, and the ItemsSource is updated from that other thread, how should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)

Comment: Shouldn't the fact that the ItemsSource is already bound (BindList) to the TreeView, and that the threaded function is updating BindList, mean that the UI should reflect this automatically?

Comment: In that function you are accessing an UI-element, which cannot be done on a background thread, you could change the collection itself but it would need to implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: But even if I remove the ItemsSource line, because BindList is being changed (and has been bound earlier, before UpdateList is ever called) shouldn't the UI reflect this?

Comment: As i said, changes to collections are only reflected if INotifyCollectionChanged is imlemented. And if you overwrite the `BindList` property you need INotifyPropertyChanged. (Also an assignment is not a binding, if you overwrite the property you need a proper binding which points to the `BindList` property, rather than passing the object currently referenced by `BindList`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `Model.GetList()` function to *property* of type `ObservableCollection<>` For example:

   `public ObservableCollection<DataItem> List { get; set; }`
2. Call `TreeView1.ItemsSource = Model.List` only once. It gives you advantages of WPF binding.
3. Create a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to load the data in `DoWork` handler. Load data to temporary collection and copy this collection to `Model.List` at `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.
   If you want to update your tree while data is loading you may look at this approach: [WPF update binding in a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505492/wpf-update-binding-in-a-background-thread)
4. Read and learn [MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) to understand the main idea of WPF developing